# Using Docker API to pull from a private registry

Tags: docker

What is the syntax to pull an image from a private registry?

I am trying to reproduce the below command with the API:

```
docker pull localhost:5000/oillio/my_app:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

It looks like I am supposted to use the images/create call.  There are 4 parameters, fromImage, fromSrc, repo, tag, and registry.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to set those parameters to reproduce the above command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something similar to this has worked for me:

```
curl -X POST localhost:2375/images/create?fromImage=localhost:5000/oillio/my_app&tag=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Where `localhost:2375` is my private server

Comment: what if the private registry requires authentication?